# Kernel of the map given by $j(m)=1\otimes m$ is in torsion module

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules, tensor-products

Let $R$ be an integral domain, $K$ its field of fractions and $M$ an $R$-module.
I want to show that the kernel of the map $j:M\rightarrow K\otimes M, m\mapsto 1\otimes m$ is contained in the torsion module $T(M)$.

So given an element $m$ of the kernel, I have $0=j(m)=1\otimes m$. I now have to prove that there exists an $r\in R$, $r\ne0$, such that $rm=0$. How do I do this though?

Comment: What have you tried? Do you know $K=S^{-1}R$, the localization of $R$ with respect to $S=R-\{0\}$? Do you know $S^{-1}R\otimes_R M=S^{-1}M$ for any multiplcatively closed subset?

Comment: @Mohan Nothing so far because I didn't know where to start. I will go over my notes again with what you just wrote in mind. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So since $K=S^{-1}R$ where $S=R\backslash \{0\}$ and $U^{-1}R\otimes_RM\cong U^{-1}M$ for any multiplicatively closed subset $U\subset R$, one has $K\otimes M= S^{-1}R\otimes M\cong S^{-1}M$ with $1\otimes m\mapsto \frac{m}{1}$ and it now follows from $0=1\otimes m$ that there exists an $r\neq 0$ with $rm=0$ by definition of the localization $S^{-1}M$.

$S$ is closed because $R$ is an integral domain.